A peculiar problem on geometry relating to finding the angle between the diagonals of a cyclic quadrilateral
A quadrilateral with side lengths $a$,$b$,$c$ and $d$ can be inscribed in a circle such that $a=\frac{1}{c}$ and $b=\frac{1}{d}$. If $∆A$ represents the area of the quadrilateral. Prove that the angle between the diagonals of the quadrilateral is $\sin^{-1}(∆A).$
My Attempt:

I tried to solve this problem by first understanding the given relationships between the sides of the quadrilateral. Given that  $a = \frac{1}{c}$  and  $b = \frac{1}{d},$ I wrote down these relationships to keep track of them.
Next, I reminded myself that since the quadrilateral is inscribed in a circle, it is a cyclic quadrilateral. For such quadrilaterals, I know the sum of the opposite angles is $$180^\circ.$$
I also looked up Brahmagupta's formula for the area of a cyclic quadrilateral, which is:
$$\Delta A = \sqrt{(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)(s-d)}$$
where (s) is the semiperimeter:
$$s = \frac{a+b+c+d}{2}$$
Given the relationships between the sides, I wrote:
$a=\frac{1}{c}$ and $b=\frac{1}{d}$ and let $c=y$ and $d=x.$
Then I substituted these into the formula for the semiperimeter:
$$s = \frac{\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y} + x + y}{2}$$
From here, I attempted to express the area $\Delta A$ using these relationships, but the expressions got pretty complicated. I wasn't quite sure how to simplify them.
I then recalled that the area can also be expressed in terms of the diagonals and the sine of the angle between them. I tried to set up the equation for the area using the diagonals $d_1$ and $d_2$:
$$
\Delta A = \frac{1}{2} d_1 d_2 \sin(\theta)
$$
However, I got stuck trying to relate this to the given side lengths and couldn't figure out how to prove it. I suspect it involves more advanced properties of cyclic quadrilaterals or a specific theorem that I might not be aware of.
I’m sure there's a clever way to connect all these pieces, but I couldn’t find it. Please anyone help me to complete the prove.

Assume $A,B,C,D$ (in this order) are the vertices of the quadrilateral, and $a=AB, b=BC, c=CD, d=DA.$
By Ptolemy's theorem, in a cyclic quadrilateral, the product of diagonals equals the sum of products of opposite sides, so
$$AC\cdot BD=AB\cdot CD+BC\cdot DA=a\cdot \frac{1}{a}+b\cdot\frac{1}{b}=2\tag 1$$
One of formulas for the area of a convex quadrilateral uses its diagonals and the angle between them. In the present case
$$\Delta \mathbb{A}=\frac{1}{2}AC\cdot BD\cdot \sin\varphi$$
With the use of $(1)$ we get
$$\Delta \mathbb{A}=\sin\varphi.$$

I completely missed it. Thanks.

Noting $AB=a$, $BC=b$, $CD=c$ and $DA=d$.
Finding the length of the diagonals $d_1=AC$ and $d_2=BD$ :
$$ d_1^2=\dfrac{(ac+bd)(ad+bc)}{ab+cd}=\dfrac{2(ad+bc)}{(ab+cd)}=\dfrac{2(a^2+b^2)}{(ab)^2+1}$$
$$ d_2^2=\dfrac{(ac+bd)(ab+cd)}{ad+bc}=\dfrac{2((ab)^2+1)}{a^2+b^2}$$
Which, according to your formula, ends the exercise.

@MINDFORGENEXUS That's ok :)

Did the modification thanks !
